# A batch file that can detect mouse movements?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to write a batch file that will have these characteristics :

1. If mouse moves - log off
2. Else run a script.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overlow!  Please take your time to learn [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :) In general we do not write code for you, but instead help you with your existing code if it has problems. So please try to solve the problem first by yourself (I'm sure google has a lot of material about this subject), and then come back when you run into a more specific problem in your code.

Answer (score 1):

check **[this](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/c/mouseSniffer.bat)** for reference.It is a self-compiled batch/c# script. I've used [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/toub/2006/05/03/low-level-mouse-hook-in-c/) as a reference.Probably you'll have to make changes to fit your scenario.